# Port forwarding - NTP сервер

Tags: linux, сеть

Сеть создана таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все компьютеры пингуются по IP-адресам, а также имеют доступ в интернет.

На машине `192.168.0.155` установлены такие правила `iptables`:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.155 --dport 33 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.167:22
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.155 --dport 88 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.167:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.155 --dport 5540 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.167:554
```

DNS сервер настроен и работает.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.0/24 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.160:53
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.0/24 --dport 1023 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.160:1023
```

К сожалению, проблема с NTP сервером. Несколько дней назад он работал с указанными правилами, теперь перестал.

```
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: я думаю, что вопрос — вне тематики сайта, т.к. на него, по-моему, не может быть ответа, который пригодится хоть кому-нибудь ещё.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я уже нашел ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было установить и настроить заново NTP сервер.

Answer (score 0):

Вы к сожалению не указали, а с какой стороны у вас интернет. А комментарии мне писать пока не дают. Судя по правилу маскарада, подозреваю, что где то за 192.168.0 подсетью.
Проблема может быть например на 192.168.0.1
Пути локализации проблемы:
1. запустить ntpq, посмотреть что выдает по команде peer
2. На машине 0.155 запустить на одной консоли tcpdump -n -i eth1 udp and port 123

на второй консоли ntpdate -d pool.ntp.org
посмотреть, что скажет ntpdate и увидит ли tcpdump уходящие с интерфейса и приходящие пакеты.
Если пакеты уходят - то так же tcpdump смотреть на 192.168.0.1 (надеюсь там *nix) есть ли пакеты на входящем интерфейсе иесть ли они далее на интерфейсе в сторону интернета.
Что бы яхоть что тоеще мог придумать мне нужно знать, что дает ntpq peer и значимые строки ntp.conf

Comment: интернет со стороны 0.155, он передается на 2.167 )
Но проблему я уже решил. Вся причина была в 0.155, у него не был сконфигурирован ntp